# Invalid LatLng Object kibana geoJSON

Tags: geojson, kibana

Kibana is unable to parse Bettermap with the following error:

```
Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, [-95.416,29.7346])
```

I'm passing the longitude/latitude as:

```
"location":"[-95.416,29.7346]"}
```

What specifically is being referenced as undefined?

Answer (score 0):

The input is wrong, you should provide and array (so loose the quotes around the array. It can also be a string, than you have to loose the [ and ]. Also be careful with the order of longitude and latitude, they differ for the string and array based types. You can find more about the input formats here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html

Also check if the field location is of type geo_point.